# How to filter the baselines(UCM) alone from describe command?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

As we are having many components , I am trying to describe all the baselines using following command

cleartool describe -l baseline:Baseline_2.1.0.13@\My_PVOB

It provides output like follows

```
"Build 13"
master replica: My_PVOB@\My_PVOB
owner: Admin
group: ABC
stream:Components_Integration@\My_PVOB
component: Baselines@\My_PVOB
label status: No Versions to Label
change sets:
promotion level: INITIAL
depends on:
  Baseline_2.1.0.13.8206@\My_PVOB (Comp1@\My_PVOB)
  Baseline_2.1.0.13.433@\My_PVOB (Comp2@\My_PVOB)
  Baseline_2.1.0.13.423@\My_PVOB (Comp3@\My_PVOB)
  Baseline_2.1.0.13.3763@\My_PVOB (Comp4@\My_PVOB)
```

Actually i want to get contents only below depends on: ( Want to get Just following contents)

```
Baseline_2.1.0.13.8206@\My_PVOB (Comp1@\My_PVOB)
  Baseline_2.1.0.13.433@\My_PVOB (Comp2@\My_PVOB)
  Baseline_2.1.0.13.423@\My_PVOB (Comp3@\My_PVOB)
  Baseline_2.1.0.13.3763@\My_PVOB (Comp4@\My_PVOB)
```

How to omit the remaining information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`fmt_ccase` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm):

```
%[depends_on]Cp
```

> (UCM baselines) The baselines that the composite baseline directly depends on

So for a composite baseline:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[depends_on]Cp" baseline:aBaseline@\apvob
```

could do the trick, except it will print only the dependent baselines on *one* line, each name separated by space, and without their associated component name.

So you need to parse that output, and for each baseline name, do a:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[component]Xp" baseline:aBaseline@\apvob
```

(Or, if your naming convention for baselines allows for it, a simple:

```
cleartool describe -l baseline:Baseline_2.1.0.13@\My_PVOB | grep Baseline_
```

would be easier!)

---

Actually, the [OP samselvaprabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399145/samselvaprabu) took the last proposition to grep what he needed from the initial output. His grep is better than my proposal, because it doesn't depend on the Baseline naming convention, but on the PVob name of said baselines:

> I am using windows so your last(simple) command gave me the idea.
>   Following command works in Dos

```
cleartool describe -l baseline:Baseline_2.1.0.13@\My_PVOB | find "@\My_PVOB)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using windows so your last(simple) command gave me the idea . Following command works in Dos . cleartool describe -l baseline:Baseline_2.1.0.13@\My_PVOB | find "@\My_PVOB)"

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: Excellent idea. i have edited my answer to include it, for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Read "fmt_ccase" manual, you'll find it over there:

```
cleartool man fmt_ccase
```

Comment: Thanks for it. but toughest concept for nominal users