# Two baselines created in ClearCase UCM

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am setting up a project using composite baselines.  When I create a baseline to send to the "Mainline" project, it always creates two baselines.  One is called "COMP_BL" and the other is "COMP_BL.####"

Is there a reason for this to happen?  Could I possibly have my setup wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your setup is right.

It will always create one baseline by component which have changed.

If your root-based component (the one with files) has changed, it got a baseline.
That means your root-less component (the one without any file, made to aggregate other components) will get also a (composite) baseline, in order to record changes in the dependencies of said rootless component.

See "[Best practice for composite baseline](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/5134.html)" for illustration.

As explained in "[do any one have batch file to apply and create label or base line in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597245/do-any-one-have-batch-file-to-apply-and-create-label-or-base-line-in-clearcase/1597297#1597297)", when you apply multiple baseline, ClearCase:

- reuse the same *title* "`COMP_BL`"
- generate a different ID "`COMP_BL.####`"

That id will be:

- "`COMP_BL`" (the title itself) for the first component to get a baseline (usually the rootless component, but there is no guarantee)
- "`COMP_BL.####`" for each other component

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically get the components baselines' names that represent the same "major" baseline?

Comment: @You can get the list of baselines for one component (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4440593/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/8132683/6309), but unless you have a rootless component which recorded in a composite baselines all the baselines put on all components on a given stream: no. Your best approach when dealing with multiple component is then rely on the *name* of the baseline (which would be the same across components) indicating that those components have been probably baselines together.

Comment: I do have a rootless component. Is it possible to get from a baseline in that rootless component, all the corresponding baselines of its sub components?

Comment: @AmirRachum yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571421/how-to-filter-the-baselinesucm-alone-from-describe-command